# How to clone a QRCode image with given content text?

Tags: node.js, qr-code

I have a QRCode image and it's content: `P01 V0N S0000000`
[image]

I tried to regenerate this image with different `matchPattern` using [node-qrcode](https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode):

```
const $qr = require('qrcode')
const text = 'P01 V0N S0000000'

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let path = `P01V0NS0000000-${i}.png`
  const opt = {
    maskPattern: i
  }
  $qr.toFile(path, text, opt, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(opt)
    }
  })
}
```

but none of generated image has the same pattern as the target:
[image]

I also tried with different `version` paramter, but all version>1 will generate a much dense pattern.

Is this QRCode image generated with some kind of `salt` to make hard to replicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to try with another version as your first image clearly is a `version 1 (21x21)`. Instead, it might be the format encoding (given the set of chars, the app might use `alphanumeric` and your original might well be `byte` for example)

As per the link you provided, I'd recommand reading [this section](https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode#manual-mode) about modes and try either with:

```
mode: 'alphanumeric'
```

or with:

```
mode: 'byte'
```

to see if any of those match your original code.

Another parameter that can change the aspect of the QR-code is the [error correction level](https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode#errorcorrectionlevel). I'd guess by default `node-qrcode` uses the highest level possible given version 1, and your original might use a lower one.

With those params, you have a set of `8(maskPattern)*2(mode)*4(errorCorrectionLevel) = 64` possible QR-codes with the same data inside, so maybe one of them will match!

---

### Edit

As your data is 16 characters long, the scope is reduced as error correction level can only have the following values ([source](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html#decisionCell)):

- `L`,`M`,`Q` for `alphanumeric` mode
- `L` for `byte` mode

Therefore, you have `(3+1)*8 = 32` possible resulting images.